# How to make an array with polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

```
class Base1
{
    private:
     int testInput; 
    public:
       Base1();
       virtual int GetRow(void) = 0;
 };

 Base1::Base1()
 {
   testInput = 0;
 }

class table : public Base1
{
   private:
    int row;    
   public:  
     table();
     virtual int GetRow(void);
};

table::table()
{   
  //Contructor
  row = 5;
}

int table::GetRow()
{
  return row;
}

int main ()
{
  Base1* pBase = new table[3];
  pBase[0].GetRow();
  pBase[1].GetRow();   //when i get to  this line, the compiler keep saying access
                           // violation.
  pBase[2].GetRow();

  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create an array of 3 table class. The requirement is I have to use Base object to do that.

```
Base1 * pBase = new table[3];
```

look fine to me. But when I tried to access each table, the compiler said it's access violation. I don't know what wrong with this code. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 though.

Answer (score 18):

**In C++, polymorphism and arrays don't mix.**

Since in general the size of the derived class is different to the size of the base class, polymorphism and pointer arithmetic don't play together nicely. Since array access involves pointer arithmetic, expressions such as `pBase[1]`  don't work as expected.

One possibility is to have an array of *pointers* to your objects, perhaps even smart pointers to simplify memory management. But don't forget to define a virtual destructor in `Base1`.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting the error because the array is statically typed to `Base1`. That means that this line:

```
pBase[1].GetRow();
```

adds the size of `Base1` in bytes to `pBase` and interprets this as the beginning of another `Base1` object, but this actually points someplace into the middle of the first `table` instance.

If you need an array of polymorphic instances, you must store them in the array (or preferably in a `std::vector`) via pointers (or preferably some form of smart pointers).

Answer (score 5):

Agnew's response was spot on. Let me explain a little more. By augmenting your code, I print out the size of a `Base1` and a `table` object as well as the addresses of the three `table` objects as they are created by the `new` operator:

```
A Base1 object is 8 bytes
A table object is 12 bytes
A table object is being constructed at 0x002977C0
A table object is being constructed at 0x002977CC
A table object is being constructed at 0x002977D8
```

As you can see those objects are spaced 12 bytes apart from each other in memory.

Now, let's print out the addresses that pBase[0], pBase[1] and pBase[2] give:

```
pBase[0] is at 0x002977C0
pBase[1] is at 0x002977C8
pBase[2] is at 0x002977D0
```

Now look at what happens: the pointers we get back are spaced 8 bytes apart. This is because the pointer arithmetic is done on an pointer whose type is `Base1` and since `Base1` is 8 bytes longs what the compiler does is to translate `pBase[n]` into `pBase + (n * sizeof(Base1))`.

Now you should be able to understand exactly why the *first* `GetRow()` works and why you crash on the second.

Comment: and , shhh.. but casting to the correct type , and then calling the method on the casted type will prevent the crash

Comment: You mean `((table)pBase)[1].GetRow()`? That will work, but it's a *horrible* thing to do and will almost certainly come back and bite you in the ass.

Comment: yes i do mean exactly that. Yes it's quite 'horrible' , but it's quite a valid way to coax the compiler into accessing the polymorphic objects at the correct addresses.

Comment: thanks guys, now I understand more about poly

Comment: @NikBougalis: `((table)pBase)[1].GetRow()` is not guaranteed to work *(even after fixing the typo)*. You mean `dynamic_cast<table*>(pBase)[1].GetRow()`? That will work.

Comment: (oops - thanks for catching the typo). The `dynamic_cast<>` does something *very* different than the C style cast I showed, whose closest C++ equivalent would be `static_cast<table*>(pBase)[1].GetRow()`. The (typo-corrected) C-style cast is *guaranteed* to work correctly in this scenario, but as I pointed out it's horrible and will almost certainly come back and bite one in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create (with `new`) all those array elements, do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    pBase[i] = new table();
```