# array of classes - delete ops

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have this code :

```
 Derived **args = new Derived*[2];
 args[0] = new Derived();
 args[0]->setname("BLABLA \n");
 cout << args[0]->getname();
 delete args[0];

 args[1] = new Derived();
 args[1]->setname("BLABLABLA\n");
 cout << args[1]->getname();
 delete args[1];
 delete [] args;
```

Is `delete [] args` required? And why?

Also, what does `Derived **args = new Derived*[2]` really do? Does it allocate space for two pointers to `Derived`? If so, then how can I dynamically create an array that contains 2 objects of type Derived on the heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `delete []` args required? And why?

Yes it is. It frees the memory allocated by `new Derived*[2]`.

> Also, what does `Derived **args = new Derived*[2]` really do?

It allocates space for two *pointers* to `Derived`. It does not allocate space for any `Derived` *objects*.

> how can I dynamically create an array that contains 2 objects of type `Derived` on the heap?

Just remove one level of indirection:

```
 Derived *args = new Derived[2];

 args[0].setname("BLABLA \n");
 cout << args[0].getname();

 args[1].setname("BLABLABLA\n");
 cout << args[1].getname();

 delete [] args;
```

But bear in mind that arrays and polymorphism don't mix. For details, see [How to make an array with polymorphism in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718527/how-to-make-an-array-with-polymorphism-in-c)

Comment: @SteveWellens: To be specific, it frees the array of pointers but definitely does __not__ free the objects the pointers point to.

Comment: Right, I just deleted my comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "It allocates space for two pointers to Derived"? so basically I just created an array of size 2 that hold pointers to an object of type Derived? if so, then how can I dynamically create an array that contains 2 objects of type Derived on the heap?

Comment: @NPE: Yes polymorphism! exactly, I need to use args[0] as a pointer to Dervived object since I'd like to use polymorphism on that object later on :$ That's why I couldn't go with the second solution you proposed