# Ambiguous overload with array passed as pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, overloading

The following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class C : public B {};

void foo(A *a) {
    cout << 'A' << endl;
}

void foo(B *b) {
    cout << 'B' << endl;
}

int main() {
    C *c = new C[10];

    foo(c);
}
```

compiles fine and prints 'B' as expected.

But when I change the `main()` function to

```
int main() {
    C c[10];

    foo(c);
}
```

I get a compiler error saying

```
test_arr.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test_arr.cpp:23:10: error: call of overloaded 'foo(C [10])' is ambiguous
test_arr.cpp:23:10: note: candidates are:
test_arr.cpp:11:6: note: void foo(A*)
test_arr.cpp:15:6: note: void foo(B*)
```

Why is it ambiguous now?  I thought an array was always just a pointer so I don't really see the difference.

**Edit:**

I just realized the whole code I posted was a bad idea to start with: As soon as you add data members to the classes and access them in the `foo` functions you will run into problems, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718527/how-to-make-an-array-with-polymorphism-in-c), since the `foo(B*)` function has no way of knowing it's actually dealing with `C` objects which potentially take more memory space.  So don't do this!

Nevertheless I am still interested in understanding why the compiler complains about ambiguity here, since I really don't see a problem with *that* here.

Comment: on vs2008, I cannot reproduce the error - and the latter test case prints 'B'.

Comment: Does foo(&c[0]) work?

Comment: [Arrays are not pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c). Where does this idea come from, anyway? Also, the pointer arithmetic you need for array access isn't going to work out when you cast an array of `C` to pointer to `B` (or `A`, for that matter); once `C` contains some data members, `b[1]` will not give you a valid object because `sizeof(B) != sizeof(C)` (and it's undefined behavior before then, as well).

Comment: in foo(B*), you can know, whether it is a C by using dynamic_cast. C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(b) in foo(B* b) and check if c is nullptr (or NULL für c++0x). If it is not nullptr, it is C.

Comment: @Gombat These classes are not polymorphic, you can't use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Barry, oh you are right.

Comment: @Wintermute: Indeed, after posting I also figured out that this code is never going to work; thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a gcc bug. The code compiles on clang.

First, both candidates are viable. From [conv]:

> A *standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>   — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, **array-to-pointer conversion**,
>   and function-to-pointer conversion.
>   — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, **pointer conversions**, pointer to
>   member conversions, and boolean conversions.

Both calls to `foo` would involve an array-to-pointer conversion (from `C[10]` to `C*`) and then a pointer conversion (from `C*` to either `A*` or `B*`). That is an allowable standard conversion.

Now, how do we rank those conversions? Amusingly, the line from the standard matches **exactly** our use-case, in [over.ics.rank]:

> Two conversion sequences with the same rank
>   are indistinguishable unless one of the following rules applies:
>   — If class B is derived directly or indirectly from class A and class C is derived directly or indirectly from
>   B,
>      — **conversion of C* to B* is better than conversion of C* to A***

We have two conversions sequences of the same rank (Conversion), that are both viable, but one is considered better than the other. The code should unambiguously prefer `foo(B* )` over `foo(A* )`. The fact that `c` is declared an array should not make it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

`C c[10]` is not a polymorphic type. You might be able to get a pointer to the first item in the array, but that is still just a `C`.

You would get slicing if you tried to cast it to `B`.

`C* c = new C();`  can be be `dynamic_cast` to `B`.

Comment: @sehe I got confused with how this question is related to conversions more than the fact that its `C[10]` is not really a polymorphic type?